# Cucumber Step Definition for finding text inside a label

Tags: cucumber

I'm new to cucumber and I have the following scenario:

```
Then I should see a "label" with "Email"
```

Code:

```
<label for="email">Email:</label>
```

I want to check and see if the label has "Email:" defined inside.

Any ideas ?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not mentioned which framework you're using with cucumber (may it be webrat, capybara...) but usually they provide you with a method called `with_scope`

So you can define steps like this:

```
with_scope("some_custom_scope") do |content|
    field_labeled(some_label).should match(/\_something_/)
end
```

Comment: Sorry about that, left out that I'm using capybara for that.

Answer (score 1):

If you use RSpec and WATIR, you could do something like this:

```
Then(/^I should see the "([^"]*)" label$/) do |text|

  expect(@browser.label(:text => text).exist?).to eq(true)

end
```